# Microsoft Visual Studio has stopped working when i click to add data set in microsoft rdlc reporpt

Tags: visual-studio-2013, dataset, microsoft-reporting

When click to add data set in Microsoft rdlc report in visual studio 2013 error came that visual studio has stopped working .

[image: Click to see Image of error]

I have already created data set that I want to refer in report by adding data set. 
but in other projects its work fine

Comment: look in eventlog for more details

Comment: @magicandre How I can see event log ?

Comment: run C:\Windows\system32\eventvwr.msc